# Resize form and controls VB 6.0

Tags: vb6

Good morning, the problem is that I am making an application where I have several forms with many objects. I work with a resolution of 1024 * 768, but when I change to a higher screen resolution, the controls are grouped on the left side of the screen. How can I control the size of the application's forms and controls so that they adapt when the screen resolution is changed from Windows?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Like Slugsie mentions, you could do this yourself but it could be challenging depending upon the complexity of your forms.  Another option is to buy a 3rd-party control to handle resizing and re-positioning of your forms.  GrapeCity and Infragistics come to mind, but I'm not sure if their ActiveX controls are still available.

Answer (score 0):

With VB6 there is no simple solution, unlike .Net.

You need to look at the Form_Resize event and in there resize/reposition controls as necessary. There is no automatic way, you pretty much have to work it all out manually.

If however this is a new development and you've just started, I'd recommend moving over to VB.Net as it has a host of features that make handling form resizing really easy to deal with.

Comment: I was afraid of that
however I had to consult to be sure
I am already migrating to vb.net, in this case it was a solution to an application that I have not migrated yet